# Haskell Type Error when Defining Monad

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a type `Effect` which represents an effect on a stack. An `Effect` can either be a successful effect which modifies a stack and optionally generates output, or it can be an error that remembers how the stack looked when it failed.

```
data Effect a = Failure a | Effect a [Int]
instance Monad Effect where
    return s = Effect s []
    (Failure debugS) >>= _ = Failure debugS
    (Effect oldS oldO) >>= f =
        case f oldS of
            (Failure debugS) -> Failure debugS
            (Effect newS newO) -> Effect newS (newO ++ oldO)
```

Binding should concatenate the results (in reverse order, I am aware). However, at the moment GHC gives me the following error message:

```
example.hs:2:10:
    No instance for (Applicative Effect)
      arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monad Effect’

example.hs:4:38:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘b’ with actual type ‘a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            (>>=) :: Effect a -> (a -> Effect b) -> Effect b
          at example.hs:4:22
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            (>>=) :: Effect a -> (a -> Effect b) -> Effect b
          at example.hs:4:22
    Relevant bindings include
      debugS :: a (bound at example.hs:4:14)
      (>>=) :: Effect a -> (a -> Effect b) -> Effect b
        (bound at example.hs:4:5)
    In the first argument of ‘Failure’, namely ‘debugS’
    In the expression: Failure debugS
```

I am new to Haskell and unused to GHC's error messages. How should I correct this error?

Answer (score 2):

As of GHC 7.10, you unfortunately need to implement `Monad`, `Applicative`, and `Functor` due to the [Functor-Applicative-Monad Proposal](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functor-Applicative-Monad_Proposal).

The reason you get the type error is because the type of `>>=` is:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

This means that the function you pass in **gives back** type `m b`. However, because you give back `Failure debugS`, this is of type `m a`, which is a type mismatch, because it essentially forces the `>>=` to conform as:

```
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m a) -> m a  -- Wrong!
```

The `debugS` that you return will have to be different.

Comment: Is there any way to constrain `(>>=)` so that its type signature is `(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m a) -> m a`?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think one approach would be to modify `Failure` to something like `data Effect a = Failure FailMsg | ...`. This allows you to essentially then propagate some data of type `FailMsg` through the `>>=` operators. Because `FailMsg` does not depend on type variable `a`, you don't have the problem you hit with the `>>=` operator's type.

Comment: @Challenger5 no this wouldn't be a monad. If you want to preserve a type parameter throughout a chain of monadic operations, it should be *another* type parameter. Something like `data Effect s a = Failure s | Effect s a [Int]` and `instance Monad (Effect s) where...` but I have no idea how to continue with this. Perhaps give a couple of use cases.

Comment: @n.m. I actually only ever want `Effect` to be used with a single type.

Comment: @Challenger5 You don't have or need a monad then. Perhaps a monoid